# ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow` on Windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pip, anaconda

[Anaconda in Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6vhf.png)

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall the current version of tensorflow using:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

After that install the correct version using:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.2 or pip install tensorflow>=2.2
```

And it should work fine. Please let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: That solved the problem, thank you!

Comment: Please mark the question as correct and close the question..